# Recursive function works, but unable to memoize

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am solving this dynamic programming question on LeetCode.com: https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/

> You are given a list of non-negative integers, a1, a2, ..., an, and a target, S. Now you have 2 symbols + and -. For each integer, you should choose one from + and - as its new symbol.  Find out how many ways to assign symbols to make sum of integers equal to target S.
> For input `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and S=`3`, output should be `5`.

The constraints are:

> The length of the given array is positive and will not exceed 20. 
> The sum of elements in the given array will not exceed 1000. 
> Your output answer is guaranteed to be fitted in a 32-bit integer.

I came up with the following code:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> n;
    int s;
    
    int helper(vector<vector<int>>& dp, int sum, int startIndex) {
        if(startIndex==n.size()) {
            if(sum==s) return dp[startIndex][sum]=1;
            else return dp[startIndex][sum]=0;
        }
        if(dp[startIndex][sum]!=-1) return dp[startIndex][sum];
        
        
        return dp[startIndex][sum]=helper(dp, sum+n[startIndex], startIndex+1) +
               helper(dp, sum-n[startIndex], startIndex+1);
    }
    
    int findTargetSumWays(vector<int>& nums, int S) {
        n=nums;
        s=S;
        vector<vector<int>> dp(21, vector<int>(1001,-1));
        
        return helper(dp, 0, 0);
    }
};
```

Without memoization using the `dp` table, the code runs fine on all 139 test cases (`139 / 139 test cases passed, but took too long.`) but obviously exceeds the time limit.  Now, on memoizing as above, I get a runtime error:

> runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x621000008d00 overflowed to 0x621000008cfc (stl_vector.h)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:933:34

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Because your sum can be negative, and you are using it for indexing. Shifting the sum by `1000` for indexing purposes will help.

Comment: Ah, good point.  Missed that.  Could you please elaborate on _Shifting the sum by 1000 for indexing purposes will help_?

Comment: Well, your sum can have values in range [-1000, 1000]. By adding 1000 to it, you will have range [0, 2000], which can be used for indexing.

Comment: @J.Doe A few calls to the vector's `at()` instead of using `[ ]` would have shown you where the code was giving the issue.  In general, if you have coded a `vector`-only solution without arrays or pointers, then a runtime error like that almost always indicates an out-of-bounds access.  Then you rewrite the code to use `at()` to see where the out-of-bounds occurs.  Then instead of a runtime error, you would get a much easier to diagnose `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks, @Dmitry!  If you convert your comment into an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thank you for teaching me to catch a fish! Next time, I'll be a little wiser! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be optimised using Dynamic Programming, having `Current Index` and `Sum` as the state.

**The problem with your solution is that `Sum` alone can be a very large number or a negative number and accessing such a large index causes runtime error as you are provided with limited memory on such platforms(Sandboxed environments). The best way, is to use a map.**

Checkout the following solution which has **Accepted** verdict on Leetcode:

```
typedef long long int LL;

class Solution {
public:

    std::map<pair<LL, LL>, LL> mp;

    LL find(int currentIndex, int len, LL S, std::vector<int>& nums){


        if(mp.find(make_pair(currentIndex, S)) != mp.end()){
            return mp[make_pair(currentIndex, S)];
        }

        if(S!=0 and currentIndex >= len){
            return 0;
        }


        if(S==0 && currentIndex==len){
            return 1;
        }


        LL ans = find(currentIndex+1, len, S-nums[currentIndex], nums) + find(currentIndex+1, len, S+nums[currentIndex], nums);

        mp[make_pair(currentIndex, S)] = ans;

        return mp[make_pair(currentIndex, S)];

    }

    int findTargetSumWays(vector<int>& nums, int S) {


        return find(0, nums.size(), S, nums);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly with dynamic programming, maybe a little bit cleaner and easier to understand:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

class Solution {
public:
    inline int findTargetSumWays(const std::vector<int> &nums, const int target) {
        int copy_target = target;
        std::vector<int> copy_nums = nums;
        int sum = std::accumulate(copy_nums.begin(), copy_nums.end(), 0);

        if (sum < copy_target || (sum + copy_target) & 1) {
            return 0;
        }

        return get_subarray_sum(copy_nums, (sum + copy_target) >> 1);

    }

private:
    static inline int get_subarray_sum(const std::vector<int> &nums, const int target) {
        std::vector<int> symbols_assign(target + 1, 0);
        symbols_assign[0] = 1;

        for (int num : nums)
            for (int index = target; index > num - 1; index--) {
                symbols_assign[index] += symbols_assign[index - num];
            }

        return symbols_assign[target];
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.